# How to rearrange my js file to use accesing property?

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to use the below code inside of my javascript compiler inside of the C# application by using Jint. But I want use below method;

```
var today = f.Today;
var datediff = f.DateDiff(date1,date2);
```

Can you rearrange my below code? I want to use it like above?

```
var f = function () {
    var today = function () {
        return 1;
    };

    var dateDiff = function (first, second) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Today = today,
            DateDiff = dateDiff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it as you described above, you must return a plain javascript object, not a function (that is, if you want to be able to call `f.DateDiff()` instead of `f().DateDiff()`).

```
var f = {
    Today: new Date(),
    DateDiff: function(first, second) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(f.Today);
console.log(f.DateDiff(dateOne, dateTwo));
```